# Why am I getting an "argument out of range exception"?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, outofrangeexception

I tried the following piece of code. I don't understand why I keep on getting an "argument out of bounds" exception.

```
private void Easy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileData =readFile();
    if (fileData.Contains(name))
    {
        int i = fileData.IndexOf(name);
        int easyScore = i + name.Length +1;
        MessageBox.Show(fileData+"  "+i);
        string newString = fileData.Substring(45, 48);
        Easy.Text=newString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably you don't correctly understand what is the second value to Substring. Read the docs

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: What is the variable 'name' ?

Comment: It's always a good idea to check the stack trace, and tell us which line is throwing the exception, as well as what you're trying to achieve with your code. However, in this case, it's most likely what Steve and Selman22 already pointed out.

Answer (score 8):

The second parameter of `Substring` is length, not the end index.If you want 3 character starting from 45 try

```
string newString = fileData.Substring(45, 3);
```

Comment: If that's the case, he's probably just looking for a file extension?   Maybe just use Path.GetExtension?

Comment: @LeeTaylor good call, the 45 is a little suspect in there too, he's assuming the fileData is at least 45 characters

Answer (score 1):

It's a little ambiguous from your question, but I would guess it's caused by your Substring method.  This is known to throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if either of your values are larger then the length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are doing a substring at index 45 of fileData with a length of 48, with no guarantee that fileData is long enough. To do this safely, you would need to check that fileData is at least 93 characters long.